# f:ajax in ui:repeat renders h:outputText but fails to render/update h:inputText

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2.2, uirepeat

I have a problem with `<f:ajax>` on a `<h:inputText>` inside `<ui:repeat>`. It successfully renders a `<h:outputText>` with the new value, but not a `<h:inputText>` (both are bound to the same property). However, if I change the `<f:ajax>` to render `@form` or `@all`, it works. But I obviously don't want/need to render the whole form.

I'm using Mojarra 2.2.4. Here's the `index.xhtml`

```
<h:form>
    <table>
        <ui:repeat var="line" value="#{myBean.lines}">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:inputText value="#{line.number}">
                        <f:ajax event="change" execute="@this" render="desc1 desc2" listener="#{myBean.onChangeLineNumber(line)}"/>
                    </h:inputText>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h:inputText id="desc1" value="#{line.desc}"/>
                    <h:outputText id="desc2" value="#{line.desc}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ui:repeat>
    </table>
</h:form>
```

And here's the relevant bit of the `@ViewScoped` bean:

```
public void onChangeLineNumber(Line line)
{
    line.setDesc("Some new text " + System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: please provide the code for the line and myBean class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a bug in state management of Mojarra's `<ui:repeat>` which is fixed as per [issue 3215](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3215) as reported by my fellow Arjan Tijms (actually for a completely different problem, the fix just happens to solve exactly your problem as well). The fix is available in [Mojarra 2.2.7](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.7/). So upgrading to at least that version should do it.

Otherwise, your best bet is to replace it by a `<h:dataTable>`, the component which is designed for exactly the functional requirement of rendering a HTML table based on a collection. It also saves some HTML boilerplate.

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{myBean.lines}" var="line">
        <h:column>
            <h:inputText value="#{line.number}">
                <f:ajax render="desc1 desc2" listener="#{myBean.onChangeLineNumber(line)}"/>
            </h:inputText>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:inputText id="desc1" value="#{line.desc}"/>
            <h:outputText id="desc2" value="#{line.desc}"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

*(note that I removed `event="change"` and `execute="@this"` from the `<f:ajax>` as those are the defaults already, there's no need to repeat the defaults)*

Comment: There was a reason we had to use a `ui:repeat` instead of `h:dataTable`, but I can't remember why. Thank you for the answer!