# JSF <f:ajax> tag not rendering my form after submitting

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I am trying to render my list of elements after invoking my Managed Bean action which is deleting one of those elements. 
Here is my jsf page code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
        <h:form id="productslist">
            <div class="row">
                <ui:repeat value="#{listProductsManagedBean.products}" var="product">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <h1>
                            <h:outputText id="outputname" value="#{product.name}"/>
                        </h1>
                        <p>
                            <h:outputText id="outputprice" value="#{product.price} #{product.currency}"/>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <h:commandLink class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Delete" action="#{listProductsManagedBean.delete}">
                                <f:ajax render="outputprice outputname"/>
                                <f:param name="id" value="#{product.id}" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </ui:repeat>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my managed bean action being invoked:

```
public void delete(){
   ProductEntity product;
   product = productEntityFacade.find(id);
   productEntityFacade.remove(product);
}
```

I want my form to be rendered and not showing the deleted element again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was making a silly mistake. I wasn't reloading the list (which is populated in the `@PostConstruct` method) in the Managed Bean, now is working using the `t:dataList` tag.

Comment: did it work as stated in the question (meaning: `<f:ajax render="outputprice outputname"/>`), or with `render="@form"`?

Comment: Didn't try it as posted in the question. I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot remove a deleted element from `ui:repeat` this way. please try `render="@form"`.

in addition, using `execute="@this"` within `f:ajax` is a better practice. you don't need to submit the whole form for delete operation.

```
<h:commandLink class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Delete" action="#{listProductsManagedBean.delete}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form"/>
    <f:param name="id" value="#{product.id}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: I don't understand how to do that. Do I have to remove the commandLink tag? And how can I call the action?

Comment: sorry for keeping it too brief, i updated my answer and added the code.

Comment: does your application hit the delete method on debug mode?

Comment: Yes, in fact if I reload the page the deleted element disappears.

Comment: which jsf implementation do you use, mojarra or myfaces?

Comment: The implementation is Mojarra.

Comment: can you switch to myfaces for a try? might be a problem similar/related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272271/fajax-in-uirepeat-renders-houtputtext-but-fails-to-render-update-hinputtext

Comment: I have imported My Faces Tomahawk and replaced ui:repeat with t:datalist, but now it doesn't even fire the delete action.

Comment: isn't tomahawk a component library built on jsf? why would you need that here?

Comment: To avoid using the ui:repeat tag. In the link you posted says it is bugged.

Comment: it's bugged only on mojarra, not on myfaces.

Comment: Yes but using datalist instead of repeat didn't solve. I have the same problem.

Comment: it's likely to be a different problem.